# ECHO "Text", sleep 2s, erase "Text", then "ECHO "Text 2", etc

Tags: shell, text, sleep, echo

I have a shell script that simply outputs events on a calendar like:

```
Event 1
Monday 10:00PM - 11:00PM

Event 2
Monday 11:00PM - 11:30PM
```

I would like the output to display one event at a time, then wait 2 seconds and replace the first event with the second - then loop back to the 1st. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that?

```
while true;
  do echo -en "\rText 1"
  sleep 2
  echo -en "\rText 2"
  sleep 2
done
```

Comment: OK - that does not work with newlines in the texts to be displayed. Maybe you can use the watch command for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing means going back and overwriting it. Not all terminals support this. But you may experiment with `tput`. Look for `tput cup` to position the cursor.